# Getting Exception Details from ASP.NET PageMethods on the Client SIde

Tags: web-services, exception, asp.net-ajax, asmx, pagemethods

I am having a pagemethod to which i give a call from my JavaScript 
say

```
Pagemethods.MyMethod(MyParameter, onsucess, onfailure);
```

In the Code behind, I have something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(Param)
{
   try{
     //DoSomething..
   }
   catch(exception ex)
   {
      //Log the exception and rethrow
      throw new exception(ex.innerexception);
   }
}
```

Now the issue i face is :

Whenever i do get an exception,
i re throw the exception from code behind

But in the onfailure  method, i just get a generic message saying that
"the server method MyMethod failed with following error:   "

I don't seem to get the exception details and only that generic exception,

How can i get the exception details on JavaScript, in order to handle it according on the UI/JavaScript side.

I have verified, that it is not an issue with custom errors settings in web.config.

Can some one enlighten to me as to what is happening here?

PS: i have stepped through each and every line of code and the exception after being logged is rethrown with the proper exception details i.e. message.

Comment: Your exception handling is very bad. After logging the exception, just use `throw;`. Your code is destroying the stack trace, and losing exception details.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand as long as you have

```
<customErrors mode="off" />
```

in your web.config, the message will be returned to client.  Are you sure you have this setting ?

To display the message associated with error you need to have oassed the name of the function as the third parameter of the page method call : this function could be as simple as:

```
function onfailure( result )
{
   alert( result.get_message() );
}
```

That's what we have and it works OK

Comment: Yes i do have custom errors mode "off"

But wht i dont get is why do even get that generic message "the server method MyMethod failed with following error: "
and only that much nothing in error details.

Comment: What code do you have in your javascript onfailure function ? Do you use get_message to extract the 'message' ?

Comment: this is how my onfailure method looks like
function onCallFailure(ex, userContext, methodName){
alert(ex.get_message());}

This is where i see that generic error message i said i get

Comment: my app does have a master page 
this master page has the script manager with page methods enabled.

In one of the pages which use the above mentioned master page, there is a page method call to MyMethod.

Comment: what gets returned from get_statusCode() and get_exceptionType() ?

Comment: get_statusCode() returns 500 
get_exceptionType returns empty string
get_message() returns the generic message i am saying

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I have the same issue and customerrors mode set to off doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

After you have set `<customErrors mode="off" />` in the `<system.web>` section of the web.config, try these functions to get all of the exception details from the PageMethod's onfailure:

```
function onfailure(error) {                
    alert("Error: " + error.get_message() + "; " + 
        "Stack Trace: " + error.get_stackTrace() + "; " + 
        "Status Code: " + error.get_statusCode() + "; " + 
        "Exception Type: " + error.get_exceptionType() + "; " + 
        "Timed Out: " + error.get_timedOut());
}
```

I've found the error's status code to be far more helpful than the error message itself.